# Change Class of DIV In Table Cell on Hover of Another Cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table like this

```
<table class="mytable">

   <tr class"table-row">
     <td class="cell-one">Lorem Ipsum</td>
     <td class="cell-two"><span class="value">dolor sit amet</span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class"table-row">
     <td class="cell-one">Lorem Ipsum</td>
     <td class="cell-two"><span class="value">dolor sit amet</span></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

By default, the span element in the row's second cell is not visible (`display: none`). 
When there is a hover event for the row's first cell, I want that span in the row's second cell to be visible.

I am able to achieve this with the hover event for the second cell using:

```
.cell-two:hover .value{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However, I can't determine how to do this for hovering over cell-one. I'm unsure if this can be done using only CSS.

I could very easily do this with jQuery but as my application is using angularJS (and mixing the two is not advised), I am looking for a angularJS solution if possible (or a vanilla JS solution is not possible via angularJS). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```html
Not sure if this is what you are looking, but this hides/shows the cell with inline HTML/CSS:

<table class="mytable">

   <tr class"table-row">
     <td class="cell-one" onmouseover="this.style.display='none'" onmouseout="this.style.display='block'">Lorem Ipsum</td>
     <td class="cell-two" onmouseover="this.style.display='none'" onmouseout="this.style.display='block'"><span class="value">dolor sit amet</span></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class"table-row">
     <td class="cell-one" onmouseover="this.style.display='none'" onmouseout="this.style.display='block'" >Lorem Ipsum</td>
     <td class="cell-two" onmouseover="this.style.display='none'" onmouseout="this.style.display='block'"><span class="value">dolor sit amet</span></td>
   </tr>

 </table>

 This works locally, not sure why is not working as a Snippet.
 I hope this helps,
 Ramon
```